# Loop over columns of shapefile in modelbuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, for-loop

I use a shapefile (rain.shp) with a bunch of columns (rain_1979, rain_1990, rain_1991, ..., rain_2015). I would like to transform every column of the shapefile into a different raster using the Feature to Raster function in Modelbuilder (ArcGis 10.4.1 for Desktop). By manually selecting Field for one of the columns (e.g. rain_1989), everything works fine. But since I have so many columns, I'd prefer to use a loop.

I tried it with a 'For' loop from 1979 to 2015. My problem is however, that as soon as I try to use a placeholders in "Field" in the Feature to Raster function, it says that the Field rain_%Value% does not exist.

Is there any way to do this in Modelbuilder?

Comment: You should provide the code that you are using to loop with currently. And if there is an exact error, provide that we well.